# force embed youtube video to mute and replay

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I don't succeed to access youtube iframe api when I embed a video.

Here's my code:

```
 <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xWPDujqIwZc?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" enablejsapi="1"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="youtube.js"></script>
```

Here's #youtube.js

```
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) 
{
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if (event.data == 0) 
    {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please check at your url in the iframe, I tested it on Jsfiddle and it displayed error instead of playing the video.

Comment: @Zeratops, have you tried with the "//" ?